# Alien book that involved humans being tested in structures

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

I can't remember the name of the author or the book but there was a sci-fi book I read in the early 2000s that was about aliens setting down these structures on Earth and throwing some people in them to test them. The hard cover sleeve was sort of tech looking with lots of purple squares and blue/green square highlights.

Most of the characters were adults and all had some kind of personality flaw or reason they were being tested. I remember one character was a veteran, I think from Vietnam. They had to navigate through different layers, I think it was a pyramid. I'm pretty sure there were lots of deadly things in the book too. The book focuses on one particular location but I think there were others referenced in the book.

Any ideas of possible books?